# I need to swap 2 files with each other C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to swap 2 files with each other. I'm trying to do this, but it isn't working. the file is replacing but the backup file is not creating. Do you have any other solution please?

```
File.Replace(newLocation,defualtSource, newLocation);
```

Comment: Try File.Copy, then File.Move?

Comment: Your call to Replace basically means "Take a backup of defualtSource to newLocation, *and then* copy newLocation to defualtSource", do you see the issue?

Comment: Are you really passing in the same path for both the sourceFileName and destinationBackupFileName parameters?  If so, that would explain the problem.  You need to provide different paths for all three parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.Move("file1.txt", "temp.txt");
File.Move("file2.txt", "file1.txt");
File.Move("temp.txt", "file2.txt");
```

Why Replace should not work, however, I do not get. Are you sure you are using it right?

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter of File.Replace is the path to the backup file. Are you sure you are passing the right arguments to the Replace method?

See the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9h163f.aspx for a sample of the arguments to pass.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap 2 files, please examine this example:

```
        const string file1Folder = "D:\\File1";
        const string file1 = "file1.txt";
        const string file2Folder = "D:\\File2";
        const string file2 = "file2.txt";

        var file1Filename = Path.Combine(file1Folder, file1);
        var file1Destination = Path.Combine(file2Folder, file1);

        var file2Filename = Path.Combine(file2Folder, file2);
        var file2Destination = Path.Combine(file1Folder, file2);

        File.Move(file1Filename, file1Destination);
        File.Move(file2Filename, file2Destination);
```

If you just want to swap the text of the two files you can use File.Replace, examine the example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-replace).